# Badges not styled according to the site where they're earned

Tags: bug, design, badges, notifications

I've earned some badges on both [security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/134392/102733) and [phycics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/275669/94353). When visiting [security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/134392/102733), I found badges belonging to [phycics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/275669/94353) became a shield, and vice versa. (Badges on [physics.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/134392/102733) are circles, while [security.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/275669/94353) has shield-like badge icons.)

I think what badges appears to be should be more consistent: they should be styled depending on the site where they're earned, rather than the site users are currently visiting.

[image]
[image]

Comment: That's a hard one to solve since that would require to include the CSS from every site in the network. Too much for this purpose if you are asking me.

Comment: @patrick one of the dups says to use the default styling for badges. Would be preferable, at least in my opinion

Comment: Yeah, that would be better.